# 2d Sorting card algorithm

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a sorting algorithm for a hand of cards and it should be sorted by type then num so the output looks like 
1 of clubs
5 of clubs
7 of clubs
3 of diamonds
10 of diamonds
king of diamonds etc...
but I can only get it to sort by suit and the output is more like
5 of clubs
1 of clubs
7 of clubs
3 of diamonds
king of diamonds
10 of diamonds etc...
does anyone know how I'd be able to do this?

```
void player::handsort() {
        int hold[2][13], count=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            if (type[i]==Clubs){
                hold[1][count]=type[i];
                hold[0][count]=hand[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            if (type[i]==Diamonds){
                hold[1][count]=type[i];
                hold[0][count]=hand[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            if (type[i]==Hearts){
                hold[1][count]=type[i];
                hold[0][count]=hand[i];
                count++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            if (type[i]==Spades){
                hold[1][count]=type[i];
                hold[0][count]=hand[i];
                count++;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 13; ++i) {
            hand[i]=hold[0][i];
            type[i]=hold[1][i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: the easy thing to do is represent a card as a single number 0 to 51. This sorts easily. To get suit do `card / 4`, to get rank do `card % 4`

Comment: use `std::sort`, it only requires you to write an `operator<` for the cards (assuming you define a struct `card`, which anyhow I would recommend)

Comment: Make sure that any sort you use is a "stable sort", otherwise the second sort may rearrange the first sort.

Comment: Its stable. Works perfectly

Comment: Why do you need 4 repetitions when the code is the same?

Comment: Off-topic:  I highly recommend using a `struct` or `class` rather than parallel arrays.

Comment: I didn't represent the cards 0-51, they're [4][13] and I can't think of how to put that to use. I can't use sort functions, have to create one from scratch. The 4 repetitions are because each one is to identify what suit the card is and to sort it accordingly. And I did use a class. I have class card which has a description, number, and type. I also have a class deck which inherits 52 cards in the form of a 2D array and a class player who gets assigned these 13 card

Comment: @T-Wayne1 "I can't use sort functions, have to create one from scratch" - nonsense.

Comment: nonsense? its for a class assignment. thats 1 of the rules I was given.

Comment: Nevermind got it

Answer (score 0):

I would consider changing your implementation to something a bit more modular.

```
enum Suit { CLUB, DIAMOND, HEARTS, SPADES };

struct Card {
    Suit suit;
    int   num;

    bool operator<(Card c) const { 
        if (suit != c.suit) 
            return suit < c.suit;
        return num < c.num;
    }
};

void handsort(std::vector<Card> &hand) { std::sort(hand.begin(), hand.end()); }
```

Remember this is C++. Make use of the free abstractions!